# Modifying displacy NER annotation tool to support overlapping entities

Tags: python, html, spacy

I am working on a tool to visualise NER matches and I am trying to resolve overlaps. I am using SpaCy's displacy as a template, and my idea was to add a function after `displacy.render()` that modifies the HTML string to match my desired output, but I am somewhat stuck. Here's my process so far:

---

Let's say I have some `text` and some `entities` (identified previously by some method):

```
text = "This is an example sentence with some super secret (and some text in between) stuff"
entities = [{"start": 38, "end": 43, "label": "SUPER"},
            {"start": 38, "end": 50, "label": "SUPER SECRET"},
            {"start": 78, "end": 83, "label": "STUFF"}]
```

We can render an HTML visualisation of these manually using displacy:

```
from spacy import displacy

example = [{"text": text,
            "ents": entities,
            "title": None}]
html = displacy.render(example, style="ent", manual=True)
```

which returns

```
<div class="entities" style="line-height: 2.5; direction: ltr">This is an example sentence with some
<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    super
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">SUPER</span>
</mark>

<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    super secret
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">SUPER SECRET</span>
</mark>
 (and some text in between)
<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    stuff
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">STUFF</span>
</mark>
</div>
```

which looks like this: [image: current html]

---

The problem here is that "super" is in a separate `<mark>` outside of "super secret". Ideally, I'd want to have something like this:

```
<div class="entities" style="line-height: 2.5; direction: ltr">This is an example sentence with
<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    <mark class="entity" style="background: #add; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
        super
        <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">SUPER</span>
    </mark>
    secret
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">SUPER SECRET</span>
</mark>
 (and some text in between)
<mark class="entity" style="background: #ddd; padding: 0.45em 0.6em; margin: 0 0.25em; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em;">
    stuff
    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; border-radius: 0.35em; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0.5rem">STUFF</span>
</mark>
</div>
```

which looks like this: [image: desired html]

So my idea was to write an `html_transform(starting_html: str) -> str` function that resolves overlapping entities and returns something like the bottom image. After writing some psuedocode though, I realised that this might be a too complicated approach and I'm still stuck with it. Does anyone know of better ways of approaching this? Any pointers would be appreciated!